# How can I plot below thing using python?

Tags: python

This is the skip-gram model

```
# Build skip-gram architecture
word_model = Sequential()
word_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform", input_length=1))
word_model.add(Reshape((embed_size, )))

context_model = Sequential()
context_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform", input_length=1))
context_model.add(Reshape((embed_size,)))

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Merge([word_model, context_model], mode="dot"))
model1.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="sigmoid"))
model1.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")

# view model summary
print(model1.summary())
```

This is the trained model

```
# Train model
    for epoch in range(1, 151):
        loss = 0
        for i, elem in enumerate(skip_grams):
            pair_first_elem = np.array(list(zip(*elem[0]))[0], dtype='int32')
            pair_second_elem = np.array(list(zip(*elem[0]))[1], dtype='int32')
            labels = np.array(elem[1], dtype='int32')
            test.X = [pair_first_elem, pair_second_elem]
            test.Y = labels
            #if i % 10000 == 0:
                #print('Processed {} (skip_first, skip_second, relevance) pairs'.format(i))
            loss += model1.train_on_batch(test.X,test.Y)
        print('Epoch:', epoch, 'Loss:', loss)
```

This is a skip-gram moodel evaluation. Could enuyone please help me to plot this series?

Comment: can you provide an example of skip_grams

Comment: what do you want to plot? If you wish to plot the losses, just append each loss into a list and use `matplotlib` like `plt.plot(losses)`. You can also use `numpy.cumsum()` to plot the cumulative sums.